# Inserting 2 different array values into database does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert 2 values from arrays into a database. There's nothing wrong with the connection, the fields where `$fullArr` and `$thumbArr` get inserted are longtexts, and when I try to insert 1 array value it works fine (`$fullArr` or `$thumbArr`). As soon as both arrays get used in the query it stops working.

The values in the arrays are data-urls.

```
private function submitPhoto() {

global $database;

$projectid = $_POST['projectid'];
$fullArr = $_POST['fullArr'];
$thumbArr = $_POST['thumbArr'];

$count = 0;

foreach($thumbArr as $key) {

// Insert Thumb

$database->query("INSERT INTO `photo` (photoid, projectid, dataurlfull, dataurlthumb) VALUES('', '" . $projectid . "', '" . $fullArr[$count] . "', '" . $key . "')");

$count++;
}
}
```

Comment: What does the SQL look like? When I get errors like this it is easiest to put all the syntax into a simple string and then call $database->query($yourSQL);   This allows you to echo the string and see where the error is (and then copy paste into your database to test it further if needed)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query:

```
$database->query("INSERT INTO `photos` (photoid, projectid, dataurlfull, dataurlthumb) VALUES('', '$projectid', '$fullArr[$count]', '$key')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are not executing the query inside the `foreach()` loop, so the last one will 'overwrite' any that you had before? Also, the `$count` is not necessary as you can use the `$key`. Try something like-

```
foreach($thumbArr as $key=>$value) {
   // Insert Thumb  
   $database->query("INSERT INTO `photo` (photoid, projectid, dataurlfull, dataurlthumb) VALUES('', '" . $projectid . "', '" . $fullArr[$key] . "', '" . $thumbArr[$key] . "')");
   $database->execute();
}
```

Be aware that you are open to SQL injection as you are using `$_POST` data without sanitizing. If you are using `mysqli_` or `PDO`, use paramatized statements

```
foreach($thumbArr as $key=>$value) {
   // Insert Thumb  
   $database->query("INSERT INTO `photo` (photoid, projectid, dataurlfull, dataurlthumb) VALUES('', ?, ?, ?)");
   $database->bindParam(1,$projectid);
   $database->bindParam(2,$fullArr[$key]);
   $database->bindParam(3,$thumbArr[$key]);
   $database->execute();
}
```